# Android Navigation bar visiblity for Android P - Detect Gesture based Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-9.0-pie

How to detect whether Navigation bar (for Bazel less device) is visible or not? I tried with different solutions for Navigation bar using **Resource Identifier**, **System UI Flag** and **KeyCharacterMap** but it is not working for me. In **Andorid P** Gesture Navigation is available which will hide navigation bar and navigation functions will run using that gesture. Is there any solution to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code on a Xiaomi device using two gesture navigation method, and for me it's working:

```
Point p = new Point();
        getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(p);
        ConstraintLayout container = findViewById(your activity main view (e.g linearLayout));

        final TypedArray styledAttributes = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
        int mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        int height = container.getMeasuredHeight();
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        int result = 0;
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
if (height + mActionBarSize + result >= p.y) {
     //you have fullscreen gesture navigation
}else{
     //navigation bar or similiar
}
```

This works because the app can now take a bigger size on screen, so it works only if the gesture navigation method does not make the "navigation bar " background.

Just be sure to use it when the main is already loaded and visible otherwise it will return 0.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If I use above code inside postDelayed it always return else block. If I use without postDelayed it always return if block.

Comment: @Shan did you execute the code after the view is displayed? You can't do it in onCreate but at least some seconds later, unfortunately